# Identificar objetos novos, removidos e modificados de duas "coleções" ordenadas usando memória extra O(1) em tempo O(N)

Tags: java, java-8, revisão-de-código

Eu tenho 2 "conjuntos" de elementos, `neo` e `old`, que tem elementos do tipo `T`, todos não nulos. Além disso, eu sei que esses elementos são identificados por uma chave `K` e eu posso extrair usando essa chave usando uma `Function<T, K> getKey`. Garanto a unicidade da chave dentro de `neo` e dentro de `old` (isto é, não existem 2 elementos de `neo` com a mesma chave, nem 2 elementos distintos de `old` com a mesma chave).

Além disso, eu garanto que os elementos em `neo` e `old` estão ordenados de modo estritamente decrescente nessa chave considerando um `Comparator<K> keyComparator`. Informalmente, como se `neo[i].key < neo[j].key` para todo `i < j`, e semelhantemente `old[i].key < old[j].key`.

Eu defino que um elemento `oldEl` foi removido se `old.contains(oldEl)` e se não existir nenhum `neoEl` pertencente a `neo` tal que `getkey.apply(oldEl).equals(getkey.apply(neoEl))`.

Eu defino uma modificação `neoEl` se `neo.contains(neoEl)` e se existir algum `oldEl` pertencente a `old` tal que `getkey.apply(oldEl).equals(getkey.apply(neoEl))`, porém `!oldEl.equals(neoEl)` (se por acaso `oldEl.equals(neoEl)`, devo considerar que o elemento aparece repetidamente).

Eu defino uma criação do elemento `neoEl` se `neo.contains(neoEl)` e se não existir nenhum `oldEl` pertencente a `old` tal que `getkey.apply(oldEl).equals(getkey.apply(neoEl))`.

Até o momento, consegui fazer o seguinte:

```java
final Consumer<T> NOOP = __ -> {};

public void doDelta(Iterator<T> old, Iterator<T> neo,
        Function<T, K> getkey, Comparator<K> keyComparator,
        Consumer<T> insertInterceptor,
        Consumer<T> updateInterceptor,
        Consumer<T> deleteInterceptor,
        Consumer<T> ignoreInterceptor) {

    final int TAKE_OLD = 1;
    final int TAKE_NEO = 2;
    final int TAKE_BOTH = TAKE_OLD | TAKE_NEO;
    int nextAction = TAKE_BOTH;
    T oldT = null, neoT = null;
    K oldK = null, neoK = null;

    if (!old.hasNext()) {
        // não há old, portanto só tem inserção
        if (insertInterceptor != NOOP) {
            neo.forEachRemaining(insertInterceptor);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (!neo.hasNext()) {
        // não há neo, portanto só tem remoção
        if (deleteInterceptor != NOOP) {
            old.forEachRemaining(deleteInterceptor);
        }
        return;
    }

    while (true) {
        if (nextAction == TAKE_BOTH) {
            if (!old.hasNext()) {
                if (!neo.hasNext()) {
                    return;
                }
                neoT = neo.next();
                nextAction = TAKE_NEO;
                break;
            }
            oldT = old.next();
            oldK = getkey.apply(oldT);
            if (!neo.hasNext()) {
                nextAction = TAKE_OLD;
                break;
            }
            neoT = neo.next();
            neoK = getkey.apply(neoT);
        } else if (nextAction == TAKE_OLD) {
            if (!old.hasNext()) {
                nextAction = TAKE_NEO;
                break;
            }
            oldT = old.next();
            oldK = getkey.apply(oldT);
        } else { //if (nextAction == TAKE_NEO) {
            if (!neo.hasNext()) {
                nextAction = TAKE_OLD;
                break;
            }
            neoT = neo.next();
            neoK = getkey.apply(neoT);
        }
        int cmp = keyComparator.compare(oldK, neoK);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            nextAction = TAKE_BOTH;
            if (oldT.equals(neoT)) {
                ignoreInterceptor.accept(neoT);
            } else {
                updateInterceptor.accept(neoT);
            }
        } else if (cmp < 0) {
            deleteInterceptor.accept(oldT);
            nextAction = TAKE_OLD;
        } else {
            insertInterceptor.accept(neoT);
            nextAction = TAKE_NEO;
        }
    }

    // entrou aqui porque acabou o old
    if (nextAction == TAKE_NEO) {
        if (insertInterceptor != NOOP) {
            insertInterceptor.accept(neoT);
            neo.forEachRemaining(insertInterceptor);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (nextAction == TAKE_OLD) {
        if (deleteInterceptor != NOOP) {
            deleteInterceptor.accept(oldT);
            old.forEachRemaining(deleteInterceptor);
        }
    }
}
```

A ideia é basicamente, a cada ciclo, saber se preciso puxar elemento do conjunto `neo`, do `old` ou de ambos; no começo precisa pegar elementos de ambos os conjuntos. Depois, o que pode acontecer enquanto houver elementos dos dois lados:

- se a chave for a mesma, pegar de ambos e testar para ver se foi atualização ou o elemento se manteve idêntico
- se a chave menor for do `old`, então esse elemento foi removido do novo conjunto de elementos e preciso pegar apenas do `old`
- se a chave menor for do `neo`, então esse elemento foi criado no novo conjunto de elemento e preciso pegar apenas do `neo`

`neo` e `old` são definidos como `Iterator<T>` para não precisar carregar a priori toda a informação desses conjuntos na memória, mas outra alternativa *lazy loading* é válida também.

Os `Consumer<T>` fazem o trabalho de interceptar caso seja descoberto se o elemento é adicionado/removido/atualizado da lista (o `ignoreInterceptor` é usado mais como curiosidade caso um elemento se repita igual nos dois conjuntos).

O `NOOP` é o interceptador trivial, descarta silenciosamente caso receba algo.

> Note que não há uso de memória extra nesse algoritmo, considerando  que os `Consumer`s, `getkey`, `keyComparator` e os `equals` das classes envolvidas sejam funções oráculo.
>
> Também levando em consideração que `Consumer`s, `getkey`, `keyComparator` e os `equals` das classes envolvidas sejam funções oráculo, farei no máximo `O(|old| + |neo|)` operações ao todo, portanto sigo que a complexidade temporal é linear no tamanho dos conjuntos.

O que me incomoda aqui são os casos quando se esgota uma das coleções, ou quando recebo uma coleção vazia. Parece que está muito convoluto e bagunçado o código. Como deixar mais limpo o código?

Teria como usar `Stream` para o fim que estou usando o `Iterator`? Isso poderia deixar mais limpo o código?

E `Spliterator`, teria alguma vantagem nele além de me garantir as características (comparador fornecido pelo próprio `Spliterator`, ordenado, distinto, não nulo)?

Comment: Vendo por cima (e sem testar muitos casos), acho que não precisa dos 2 primeiros `if`'s, pode ir direto para o `while(true)`: se `old` está vazio, ele pega o primeiro elemento de `neo`, seta `nextAction = TAKE_NEO` e interrompe o loop. Depois ele cai no penúltimo `if` e executa `insertInterceptor` nos elementos de `neo`. E se `neo` for vazio, acontece algo similar e ele acaba caindo no último `if`, executando o `deleteInterceptor` em todos os elementos de `old` (ou seja, o mesmo que os primeiros `if`'s fariam). Não sei se o código fica mais claro com ou sem esses `if`'s, mas enfim...

Comment: Quanto ao restante, não sei se dá pra melhorar. Eu não tenho usado streams tanto assim, então talvez até tenha algum jeito mirabolante, mas chutaria que não vale a pena :-) (mas claro, vamos esperar se alguém responde e mostra que estou errado). Pra mim já está claro o bastante, mesmo que tenha que verificar várias vezes se ainda tem elementos restantes...

Comment: @hkotsubo tem razão, esses `if`s são artefatos de uma versão anterior, para evitar complexidade adicional no consumo das coisas terminais, mas que acabou se tornando desnecessário

Comment: Não sei se é suficiente para uma resposta, mas enfim, joguei a lógica de pegar o próximo elemento em um método, e acho que ficou um pouco mais limpo, pois eliminei a necessidade do `nextAction` e não fica um monte de `hasNext` espalhados: https://ideone.com/NBHCrn - nem tentei com streams porque acho que não precisa - e também por preguiça e falta de conhecimento mais aprofundado da API :-) E também não fiz testes extensivos, provavelemente vai ter algum caso que eu não cobri...

Comment: Achei que ficou muito melhor de ler agora, com essas modificações, @hkotsubo